# Nested prototypes in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojure, prototype, clojurescript, nested-function

Suppose I have:

```
function A(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

A.prototype.b = function(y) {
  y = y;
};
```

This translates to

```
(deftype A [x]
  Object
  (b (y)
    (set! (.-y js/this) y)))
```

My question is - how do we represent nested prototype functions?

For example:

```
function C(s) {
  this.s = s;
}

C.prototype.d = function(t) {
  t = t;

  return e(2);

  function e(u) {
    return u * u;
  }
};
```

If I were to have a guess - I would say:

```
(deftype C [s]
  Object
  (d (t)
    (set! (.-t js/this) t)
    (let [e = (fn [u] (* u u))]
      (set! (.-e js/this) e)
      (e 2))))
```

Can you please help me out with how to represent e(u) in ClojureScript?

Comment: IMO it's unclear what you are asking. Wow would you use the function `e` in JavaScript, considering it's not accessible from anywhere outside function `d` and you don't seem to be using it inside it?

Comment: Additionally the first translation seems wrong to me for a couple of reasons. On one hand the JavaScript function `b(y)` is not assigning the value of the `y` parameter to property `y` of your object; `this.y = y;` would do that. On the other hand the ClojureScript code has some syntax errors: `defType` should be `deftype`, the arguments in the `Object` protocol function `b` are  a list but should be a vector and the first argument passed to a protocol function is the object itself so the argument vector for a function that takes a single argument should be `[this y]`.

Comment: Thanks @juan.facorro that's helpful. The capital case is a java-ism quietly creeping in, now fixed. The example is of course somewhat contrived. I've updated it to use the function. Any thoughts would be much appreciated